# Table td and jquery - set same number of TD for each TR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an HTML table that has 2 cell for each row.

I use jquery-ui-sortable by drag and sort "td", but the TD number for each line unfortunately can change.

I wish that after a sort, the "td" is to order automatically so that they return to being two for each row.

Thanks

```js
 $(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({items: 'td'});
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table id="sortable">  
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you need to re-group the `td` elements in to rows of 2 after the sorting action finishes. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    items: 'td',
    stop: function() {
      var $table = $('#sortable');
      var $tds = $table.find('td');
      $table.empty();
      for (var i = 0; i < $tds.length; i += 2) {
        $tds.slice(i, i + 2).wrapAll("<tr></tr>").parent().appendTo($table);
      }
    }
  });
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table id="sortable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It works perfectly, BUT ... after the "stop" the "sort" function remains inactive until I do not make the second click.
Unfortunately this is seen only in my software ... code is too big to be posted here